# Thinktecture Identityserver elevated login for admin page

Tags: authentication, thinktecture-ident-server, identityserver3

I'm creating a site where I want to allow a administrator to log in with a Username Password combination, for his normal administrative tasks. But once he need to do some "dangerous" tasks, I want to make him log in using 2FA (only once), and thus elevate his permissions for the current session.

Does anyone know how to do this, or at least point me in the right direction.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

When you log in you have to request the scope you want, so just make sure that your client has both scopes available but you only ask for the scope you need.

Ex: create an 'admin' scope and a 'dangerous' scope and make both scopes available to your client. On initial login just ask for 'admin' but when they hit the dangerous page, send another login request but ask for both 'admin' and 'dangerous' scope.

Also, if only certain admins can do the dangerous task, make sure to only give those admins the 'dangerous' claim. You can manually put that claim in the UserClaims table, or if you are using MembershipReboot as your database access, use the 'AddClaim()' method on the useraccount object.

**Update:**
Sorry, this answer is unrelated to two factor authentication, more related to how to add a second scope to the user's token.

**Update:**
For example, if you are using the 'resource owner' flow, your original login request, with only 'admin' scope, looks like:

```
POST /ids/connect/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://mywebsite.com
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8

 grant_type=password&username=billybob&password=mypassword&scope=admin&client_id=MyClientId&client_secret=MyClientSecret
```

Then when you want to get the 'dangerous' scope, do another login the same way but add the 'dangerous' scope to your request (separated by a space), the access token you get back will now have both scopes (admin and dangerous):

```
POST /ids/connect/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://mywebsite.com
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8

grant_type=password&username=billybob&password=mypassword&scope=admin dangerous&client_id=MyClientId&client_secret=MyClientSecret
```

Comment: Thx, I can see what you mean, but can you explain how to explicitly send another login with the additional scope, in mvc? Currenly I've only set scope configuration in startup owin startupclass.

Comment: I added an update; not sure how you are logging in right now (are you using a library function call?) so I updated with what you would see on the wire

Comment: If I'm not misstaken does Resource owner not support 2fa, currently I was aiming to use the hybrid flow.

Comment: Okay my apologies, my answer has nothing to do with 2FA, I did not know the acronym, I thought you were just trying to prevent the user from using the dangerous method without explicitly knowing it was dangerous. This post from Brock seems to indicate that there is 2fa example code in the AspNetIdentity sample, so that may help you:  https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/issues/29

Comment: If you combine this method, with adding a claim when 2FA is used, you could probably get what you need.